# Wordpress get_users() returning all users with a compare query

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to figure out why all users are getting returned with this query. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function user_main(){

    $args = array(
        'meta_key'     => 'profilepicture',
        'meta_value'   => '3',
        'meta_compare' => '='
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $blogusers = get_users( $query );

    // Array of WP_User objects.

    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {

        $current_meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'profilepicture', true); 
        write_log($user->ID . ' ' . $current_meta);
    }

}
```

Comment: Miguel Dey  did you checked the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `meta_query` that contains one or more array.
Also you may try this as below.

```
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query();

$meta_query->parse_query_vars( array(
    'meta_key'     => 'profilepicture',
    'meta_value'   => '3',
    'meta_compare' => '='

) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your are trying to get users based on meta-key=>meta-value comparison. So you need to use `meta_queries` like below:-

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
      'key'     => 'profilepicture',
      'value'   => '3',
      'compare' => '='
    )
);

$users = get_users( $args );
```